# Recibir un objeto como parametro en controlador PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, ionic

Estoy trabajando con una api en moviles la cual envia esta data mediante `POST`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsuarioProvider {

  datos: any;
  api: string = 'http://10.5.10.230/TaxisPlu/moviles/app_cliente/registrar_usuario/';

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello UsuarioProvider Provider');
  }

  crear_usuario(datos) {
    let body = datos;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(this.api, body, {
      headers: headers,
      method: "POST"
    }).map(
      (res: Response) => { return res.json(); }
      );
  }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo recibe un controlador

```
public function registrar_usuario() {
       ///COMO LEER ESA INFORMACION
    }
```

Mi duda es como leer el Form Data en mi PHP.
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si lo envías a través de POST, en tu función puedes leer esos valores usando la clase input de codeigniter, en código seria algo así:

```
public function registrar_usuario() {
  ///COMO LEER ESA INFORMACION
  $name  = $this->input->post("name");
  $lastname  = $this->input->post("lastName");
  //Y así con los demas campos.
}
```

Comment: No funciona :C.

Comment: Que error obtienes?

Comment: INSERT INTO app001_usuario VALUES (null,'1','','','','','1','','','',NOW()); que todo esta vacio

Comment: Los datos los envias por ajax, o como los estas enviando?

Comment: Mediante ionic su http

Comment: headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

Comment: Edite mi post..